# C++ Xcode constructor error

Tags: c++, xcode

Have just started to move my project over to Xcode and when trying to build my project I get errors on my constructor definitions.
On the default constructor I get "Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers" and on the other constructor I get:

1. "Expected ')'"
2. Field has incomplete type 'Button::Button'
3. Non friend-class member 'string' cannot have qualified name

```
#include <string>

#ifndef BUTTON_H
#define BUTTON_H

namespace interface1
{
class Button
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        float xPos;
        float yPos;
        float width;
        float height;

    public:
        //Default constructor
        Button::Button();
        //Constructor with id, x, y, width and height parameters
        Button::Button(std::string, float, float, float, float); 

        //Getters and setters
        std::string getName();
        float getX();
        void setX(float);
        float getY();
        void setY(float);
        float getWidth();
        void setWidth(float);
        float getHeight();
        void setHeight(float);
        bool isClicked(int, int);
        void draw(int, float, float, float, float);
};
}
#endif
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the `Button::`.

Comment: Thanks. How come I needed that in visual studio but not xCode?

Comment: You didn't need it in VS either

Comment: That is a parsing bug (or feature depending on how you look at it) in VS. No. No. No. Its a bug in VS.

Comment: @chris: put your comment as an answer. Then you can get the votes you deserve for being first, the OP can accept and we can move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the constructors are inside your class definition, they, like the other member functions, don't need the `Button::` prefix. Some compilers still accept extra qualification and some do not.

```
class Button {
    Button(); //already in class scope, so no extra qualification needed
};
```

On the other hand, when you define these members outside of the class, you do need the qualification. Otherwise, it makes a new function (at least for non-constructors, which have a return type):

```
class Button {
    Button();
    void foo();
};

void foo(){} //new function, not Button::foo()
void Button::foo(){} //definition of member function
Button::Button(){} //definition of constructor
```